# Is there a PPA to get the latest Mono and Monodevelop versions?

Tags: ppa, mono, monodevelop

I need to program dot net apps via Ubuntu, so where can I get them because I always failed to compile the source??

Comment: You can always search ppa example: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=monodevelop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search Launchpad for PPAs:

`https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=monodevelop`

The top few there give you the choice between stable, beta and bleeding edge software.

Even if you understand the inherent risks in running unreleased software, be aware that these PPAs are mostly maintained by individuals and you're installing software from these people. You should ask yourself:

- Do you trust the maintainer? You're giving them root on your system.
- Is it safe to run this version of Mono on Ubuntu? Will it break things that depend on other versions?
- Will I be at risk if a security flaw is found in one of these packages? Do I need *urgent* security patches and will this repo give me them?

I'm not saying all PPAs are evil or wrong, just be aware about what you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatives
Add the Mono Project GPG signing key (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to root):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

Next, add the package repository (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to root):

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Update your package cache if necessary (i.e. run apt-get update), and run a package upgrade to upgrade existing packages to the latest available. Then install Mono as described in the Usage section.

Note: While the APT package is built against Debian Wheezy, it is compatible with a number of Debian derivatives (including Ubuntu) which means you can use the same repository across all these distributions.

Comment: +1 - this is the best option.  Official packages from an official repository.

Comment: This is now deprecated apparently :'( Why, I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of google searching I've found them [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop).

Comment: After a bit of searching you found something completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is a ppa for Mono 4.x
[https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekeks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest)

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:keks9n/monodevelop-latest
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install mono-complete

this should do the trick.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Last updated in 2012

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the other answers is https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+archive/monoxide which is "maintained by official Debian/Ubuntu Mono team".

Comment: Last update is in 2013